# Cannot upgrade packages short after a fresh install of 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kde

I'm using distribution KDE Neon which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When doing

```
# apt update
# apt dist-upgrade
```

I'm getting these results:

```
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  debconf-kde-data libcln6 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdebconf-kde1 libllvm3.8 libokular5core7 libqmi-glib1 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 qapt-deb-installer
  qt5-assistant qttools5-dev-tools snap-confine ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libqalculate5-data libqalculate5v5 qtvirtualkeyboard
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-xapian-index cryfs curl docker-neon drkonqi drkonqi-pk-debug-installer encfs kde-config-plymouth kwin-wayland kwin-wayland-backend-drm libcfitsio2 libchm1 libcolorcorrect5
  libcrypto++9v5 libcurl3 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libevent-2.0-5 libkf5kiogui5 libmarkdown2 libminizip1 libokular5core8 libqalculate14 libqalculate14-data libqmi-glib5 libqt5test5
  libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libre2-1v5 libtinyxml2-2v5 libwebpdemux1 libxapian-1.3-5 linux-headers-4.4.0-119
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic okular-extra-backends plasma-vault plasma-workspace-wayland
  pulseaudio-module-gconf python3-xapian1.3 qml-module-qtwebengine qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin xwayland
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor apt-transport-https avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon bind9-host binutils bluez-cups bluez-obexd ca-certificates catdoc cracklib-runtime cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin
  desktop-file-utils distro-info-data dnsmasq-base dnsutils eject firefox fwupd fwupdate fwupdate-signed gdbserver gstreamer1.0-x gwenview hdparm imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16
  imagemagick-common iproute2 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kdeplasma-addons-data kio-extras kio-extras-data krb5-locales kwin-addons less libapparmor-perl libappstream-glib8
  libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2 libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbind9-140 libbluetooth3 libcrack2
  libcurl3-gnutls libdfu1 libdns-export162 libdns162 libexiv2-14 libfdisk1 libfwup0 libfwupd1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgd3 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-bin libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140
  libisccfg140 libjasper1 liblouis-data liblouis9 liblwres141 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0
  libmysqlclient20 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnm0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libnuma1 libparted2 libpci3 libpcsclite1 libplist3 libplymouth4 libpoppler-qt5-1
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libpython-stdlib libqapt3 libqmi-proxy libraw15 libruby2.3 libsane libsane-common libsmartcols1 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libxatracker2 linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic logrotate lshw makedev mesa-vdpau-drivers
  modemmanager multiarch-support mysql-common nano neon-desktop neon-settings network-manager ntfs-3g okular openssh-client openssl os-prober parted pciutils
  plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python
  python-apt-common python-minimal python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-pil python3-software-properties qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard resolvconf rsync ruby2.3 sane-utils
  sensible-utils snap-confine snapd sni-qt software-properties-common squashfs-tools sudo tcpdump thermald tzdata ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-standard unattended-upgrades uuid-runtime va-driver-all wget wpasupplicant xdg-user-dirs xfonts-utils xfsprogs xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
  xul-ext-ubufox
173 upgraded, 45 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/281 MB of archives.
After this operation, 641 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [S/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 140054 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../drkonqi_5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking drkonqi (5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/drkonqi_5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi', which is also in package plasma-workspace 4:5.8.5-0neon+16.04+build61
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/drkonqi_5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/drkonqi_5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16_amd64.deb` but no luck.

In other computers with KDE Neon, I can upgrade any package with no issues.

Any help please?

**UPDATE**

In a computer that works ok:

```
# apt-cache policy drkonqi plasma-workspace
drkonqi:
  Installed: 5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16
  Candidate: 5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16
  Version table:
 *** 5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.12.3-0neon+16.04+xenial+build15 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.12.2-0neon+16.04+xenial+build14 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.12.1-0neon+16.04+xenial+build13 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
plasma-workspace:
  Installed: 4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build120
  Candidate: 4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build120
  Version table:
 *** 4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build120 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build119 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build118 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.12.3-0neon+16.04+xenial+build117 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.5.5.2-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     4:5.5.5.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

In the computer with the described problem:

```
$ apt-cache policy drkonqi plasma-workspace
drkonqi:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16
  Tabla de versión:
     5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.12.3-0neon+16.04+xenial+build15 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.12.2-0neon+16.04+xenial+build14 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.12.1-0neon+16.04+xenial+build13 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
plasma-workspace:
  Instalados: 4:5.8.5-0neon+16.04+build61
  Candidato:  4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build120
  Tabla de versión:
     4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build120 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build119 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build118 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
     4:5.12.3-0neon+16.04+xenial+build117 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4:5.8.5-0neon+16.04+build61 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.5.5.2-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     4:5.5.5.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

One difference I see is:

```
4:5.8.5-0neon+16.04+build61 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy drkonqi plasma-workspace` (add to the question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by one of these two reasons:

- You are mixing packages from two slightly incompatible repositories.
- There is just a packaging error.

Either way, in non-core packages it's usually safe forcing the installation with dpkg and then resume the operation.

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/drkonqi_5.12.4-0neon+16.04+xenial+build16_amd64.deb
```

Mandatory disclaimer from the [dpkg manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html):

> Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts only. Using them without fully understanding their effects may break your whole system.

After forcing the overwrite of that file, you can probably resume your upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```